# Passing an input into a python function

Tags: python

I have the below function which asks the user for a file and then returns the lines in that file (excluding the lines that contain a `-` symbol).

However I have an error with the function. While it does ask for input, this is not passed into the function. Would anyone be able to help me with where I went wrong? Thank you

```
filename = input('input the filename: ')

def read_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        content = [line for line in file if '-' not in line]
    return content
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not call the function!
Add this line to your code:

```
content = read_from_file(filename)
```

And you will be good.
Your code should be something like this:

```
filename = input('input the filename: ')

def read_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        content = [line for line in file if '-' not in line]
    return content

content = read_from_file(filename)
```

Good luck!